# changing into directory named "NO NAME"

Tags: macos, terminal, sh, cd

I have a thumb drive named "NO NAME"

I want to write a shell script that will find the path of this thumb drive, and will change the directory into that thumdrive.

The below code will successfully print out /Volumes/NO NAME

```
export usb=$(system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -oE '/Volumes/.*$' | tail -1)
```

My problem is that when I try to run the below command

```
cd $usb
```

I get an error saying theirs no directory named Volumes/NO

Obviously its not picking up "NAME" because their is a space in-between, but how do I fix this? I do not want to ditch the idea of assigning that directory path to a variable then calling the variable to change the directory... and I also cannot change the usb name.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the path:

```
cd "$usb"
```

In fact you should always do that if you use variables that shell "unfolds" prior use.

Comment: Owrlowski I have already tried that and i get  the following error: ./file.sh: line 2: cd: “??: No such file or directory

Comment: and what's the output of `system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep -oE '/Volumes/.*$' | tail -1`?

Comment: @python_beginner_coder You're using a fancy unicode quote, rather than a plain ASCII double-quote. You may be using a text editor that's "helpfully" doing "smart quote" conversion for you -- this will break shell scripts horribly. You should either turn this feature off in the editor, or use an editor that doesn't mess with your typing like this (I like [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html)).

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski the output of the command is:    /Volumes/NO NAME

Comment: then check what @GordonDavisson suggested - your script may contain some odd characters, you may want to add the whole script to your question (or at least line 2)